# Safely move (rarely changing) operating system directories to SSD drive

Tags: filesystem

I would like to move some directories that contain binaries to an SSD drive. How should I safely go about it?

1. /usr
2. /opt

Please consider *safely* emphasized.

[14.04.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a full system backup. (Read [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) first)
2. Make a full file back-up (Déjà-dup, BackInTime, rsync, ...)
3. Boot the LiveCD of the Ubuntu version you're currently running
4. Go to `gparted`, choose the SSD, create a partition 25% larger then the total size of /usr and /opt, format as ext4
5. Get the `blkid` of the new partition
6. Make an additional back-up only of the `fstab` file
7. Edit the `fstab` of the system and add the correct mount parameters for the new partitions, **but do not save yet!**
8. `cp --force --preserve --recursive --verbose /dev/HDD/opt /dev/SSD/opt 2>>/tmp/copy_error.txt` (and `usr` too of course\
9. Verify there are no errors copying.  If there are errors, correct manually.
10. Rename the old `/opt` and `/usr` to `/opt_old` and `/usr_old`
11. verify the copy with `diff -r /dev/SSD/opt /dev/HDD/opt_old` (and `usr`)
12. Save `fstab`
13. `mount --all`

## If

(And that's a big if!)

1. for any of the steps above you go "Huh? What's that?"
2. you have an encrypted FS
3. you have any other kind of non-standard non-plain non-Vanilla Ubuntu install

***don't do it!***

### Voilà: That's the safest way!

Comment: I am going to try this on a brave day!

Comment: Am I to take it that Ubuntu does not need to know through some configuration file, on which device to look for those directories, and it just sees them when it bootstraps, just because they are located on any mounted volume?

Comment: Read the [system back-up article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)! (you're user type 4)

Comment: You've been using Windows for too long!  ;-)  **Linux has no drive letters!**  If something is mounted in the root, it's in the root!  Done!

Comment: I hope that's a compliment :) I can fix everything with a live DVD if it screws up for any reason. Backing up would take hours.. Yes you are right about the W word.

Comment: Chat?  Ubuntu general room????